# Left-invariant Riemannian metric on $\text{SL}_3(\mathbb{R})$ under right-translation

Tags: lie-groups, riemannian-geometry

Given any left-invariant distance $\text{d}$ on $\text{SL}_3(\mathbb{R})$ (meaning $\text{d}(a,b) = \text{d}(ca,cb)$ for all $a,b,c \in \text{SL}_3(\mathbb{R})$) which is induced by a left-invariant Riemannian metric, can one say something explicit about how this distance behaves under right translation?

For example, when I have an element $x \in \text{SL}_3 (\mathbb{R})$ with $\text{d}(x,e) < \varepsilon$,

- can one give an upper bound for $\text{d}(xy,y)$, where $y \in \text{SL}_3(\mathbb{R})$ is arbitrary?
- is there a constant $C>0$ such that $\text{d}(xy,y) < C \varepsilon$?

Comment: Induced by which Riemannian metric?

Comment: Indeed, the space of left-invariant Riemannian metrics on $\mathrm{SL}_3(\mathbf{R})$ has dimension $36=8.9/2$, while the subset of those that are right invariant by some compact subgroup has dimension 4=3+1. Maybe the OP assumes right-invariance under $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ (which characterizes the Riemannian metric up to positive scalar multiplication); hopefully it will soon be clarified.

Comment: Made some changes, hope that clears things up a bit. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Indeed. Hope now it's all there.

Comment: The answer is no to both questions (if $x\neq e$). Indeed, write $d(xy,y)=d(y^{-1}xy,e)$, and observe that the only conjugacy class of $\mathrm{SL}_3(\mathbf{R})$ with compact closure is $\{e\}$.

Comment: On a connected Lie group with a left-invariant Riemannian metric, for the corresponding left-invariant distance, right translations act as maps with bounded displacement, and as bilipschitz homeomorphisms (actually analytic diffeomorphisms). But you seem to be interested in the action of varying right translations on individual elements, which is thus more a question about the shape of conjugacy classes.

Comment: That's helpful, thank you.
But is there a straight-forward way to calculate such a Lipschitz constant when given a fixed $y$, for example when $y$ is the diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $e^{\frac{1}{2}}$, $e^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and $e^{-1}$?